# Writing a function that calculates sine for inputted number of terms. MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, trigonometry

i cannot for the life of my figure out how to make a function to do this in MATLAB.. i am completely new to MATLAB and i really dont know where to start. i know how to write a function to calculate the factorials but i cant figure out how to add each next term up to the number of terms i want, using a loop.. some help would be appreciated. [image: here is the problem]

Comment: What have you tried? You can't just give us your homework and say "Here do this for me."

Comment: it is homework, and we are supposed to work in groups. but i dont have  a group since i live extremely far from my school and dont have time to collaborate. i am completely new to MATLAB and i really dont know where to start. i know how to write a function to calculate the factorials but i cant figure out how to add each next term up to the number of terms i want, using a loop.

Comment: But, essentially, what's the question? Sine Taylor's series or what?

Comment: the person is supposed to be able to call the function and then the function ask to how many terms the person would like to evaluate to. based on how many terms they would like to evaluate to, the function should spit out the sin function evaluated from the 1st term, then the first and second terms, then the first... all the way up to the last terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer myself.. note that there is a difference between sinx and sin(x)

```
function  [sinx, error] = sinx_approx(x)
%   approximates the value of sin(x), the approximation is more accurate as
%   the number of terms selected is increased. 

n= input('Up to how many terms would you like to evaluate?');

sinx=0;
for i=1:1:n
    sinx=(-1)^(i+1) * x.^(2*i-1)/ factorial(2*i-1)+ sinx;
    error=((sin(x)-sinx)/sin(x))*100;
    display(sinx);
    display(error);
end    



end
```

%%Factorial is a built in command

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

`syms x
Y = sin(x);`

`Y_1 = taylor(Y,1);`

Taylor will expand Y_1 in a series of the first order. If you want an expansion of order `n` just type in `taylor(Y,n)`

If you wanna evaluate the Taylor series in a point `x0` you then call

`subs(Y_1,x0)`